# Compare results of two mysql queries and get result in one query

Tags: mysql, database

I've a situation. I've two tables `vehicles` and `job`. What I need is the list of vehicles which don't have a job. Means I need `vehicles` where vehicle id is not available in `job`.

I tried:

```
SELECT v.id, v.registration_number
FROM vehicles AS v
LEFT JOIN job j ON j.vid = v.id
WHERE v.uid = ?
AND j.vid <> v.id
AND TO_DAYS(j.home_day2) - TO_DAYS(NOW()) <=11
AND TO_DAYS(j.home_day2) - TO_DAYS(NOW()) >=0
ORDER BY v.id DESC
```

But this doesn't return any records even there's vehicles without job.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

UPDATE:

If anyone have the example where you could check whether the corresponding result is available in other table and exclude that result based on a condition.

Comment: Why you have `WHERE v.uid = ?` ? More over its better to provide some sample data and expected output.

Comment: that query is all over the place. its not even joining the job table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, according to your logic.

```
   select v.id from
      vehicles v
        left join job j
          on v.id = j.vid 
            and home_day2 < now() + interval 11 day
            and home_day2 > now()
      where j.vid is null
    order by v.id desc;
```

But if i can hazard a guess at what you want, instead of what your query shows, it might be this:

```
   select v.id
     from vehicles v
        left join jobs j
          on v.id = j.vid 
            and j.home_day2 < now() + interval 11 day   
     where j.vid is null
     order by v.id desc;
```

Which will give you all vehicles with either no job ever, all vehicles with no current job, and all vehicles due back in the next 11 days.

[Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6ea4/11)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried above but it gives no results no matter what.

Comment: then i have your schema wrong - see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6ea4/10 for a sample of those above queries and how i think your data is

Comment: Finally it worked! I just had to mold it properly as per my need. Because your fiddle worked so it had to work for me!!

Answer (score 1):

I assume the main issue with your query is that it does not contain `jobs`.  You are also not using the `left join` correctly, and there is no reason to use `to_days` for this . . . especially because that can prevent the use of an index.  Instead:

```
SELECT v.id, v.registration_number
FROM vehicles v LEFT JOIN
     jobs j
     ON j.vid = v.id AND
        j.home_day2 <= date_add(current_date, interval 11 day) AND
        j.home_day2 > current_date
WHERE v.uid = ? AND
      j.vid IS NULL
ORDER BY v.id DESC
```

This assumes that the `home_day2` value has no time component.  The logic is only slightly different if that is true.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query should be like this

```
SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE vehicle_id NOT IN (SELECT vehicle_id FROM jobs GROUP BY vehicle_id);
```

This query will give all vehicles those don't have jobs. You can put further condition on INNER QUERY

```
SELECT vehicle_id FROM jobs GROUP BY vehicle_id;
```

like jobs between specific date etc as given below:

```
SELECT vehicle_id FROM jobs GROUP BY vehicle_id WHERE TO_DAYS(j.home_day2) - TO_DAYS(NOW()) <=11 AND TO_DAYS(j.home_day2) - TO_DAYS(NOW()) >=0
```